# Replace a recurring string with part of it

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Let's say I have the following text: (example)

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>col1</span>
    </td>
    <td>col2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text1</td>
    <td>
      <span>text2</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to replace all `<span>%</span>` by `%`, and I've come up with a solution like this:

```
replace(/<span>(.*)<\/span>/gi, function(full, text){return text;})
```

It replaces from the first `span` until the last one by only one occurrence, therefore the whole structure of my table is messed up.

How could I tell JS to replace each occurrence by the right one and not everything at once? The solution needs to be in Javascript obviously. I hope my example is not too "simple" and bugged to avoid any confusion.

Comment: obligatory http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: @MikeSamuel ... which means not possible?

Comment: it is possible to do certain operations on HTML using regular expressions, but you are very likely to get it wrong, and the resulting code will be very brittle -- even if correct, minor changes to requirements will require a complete rewrite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.*` is greedy, so will happily match `</span>...<span>`.  Replace it with `[\s\S]*?` which is non-greedy, but (unlike `.`) matches any character including newlines.

```
/<span>([\s\S]*?)<\/span>/gi
```

Better yet, parse it properly to a DOM and then change the spans there.

EDIT:

Rather than learn how to kind-of-parse HTML with regular expressions, your time would be better spent learning the DOM manipulation tools that are better suited to this problem.

To parse the HTML, you can do

```
var container = document.createElement('DIV');
container.innerHTML = myStringOfHTML;
```

Then

```
container.getElementsByTagName('SPAN')
```

will get all the SPANs.

Finding the ones that contain only a text node is simple:

```
var spans = container.getElementsByTagName('SPAN');
for (var i = 0, n = spans.length; i < n; ++i) {
  var span = spans[0];
  // do work here
}
```

to fold the children into the parent,

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('SPAN');
for (var i = 0, n = spans.length; i < n; ++i) {
  var span = spans[0];
  while (span.firstChild) {
    span.parentNode.insertBefore(span, span.firstChild);
  }
  span.parentNode.removeChild(span);
}
```

Comment: I agree with using the DOM, but unfortunately, I cannot edit it as the current HTML page needs to stay the same to the user, but your remarque about the DOM, led me to this solution (I'm using jQuery): http://api.jquery.com/clone/ I'm just hoping "cloning" a part of the document won't slow down the browser.

Comment: @Nicolas, Yeah.  Sometimes performance necessitates complicated/brittle code, but I would try the simple solution first.

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly, thank you. Still, I was curious about your DOM solution, and I think, although that is a more robust solution, is could come to a cost on the user side.

Answer (score 0):

I get that HTML and regexes don't go well together generally, and @MikeSamuel has a good solution for using the DOM, but it is really simple to do with regex (in this case).

```
var text = '<td>Hello</td> <td><span>WORLD</span></td> <td>Begin</td> <td><span>AGAIN</span></td>';
text.replace(/<span>([\s\S]*?)<\/span>/gi, '$1');

-> "<td>Hello</td> <td>WORLD</td> <td>Begin</td> <td>AGAIN</td>"
```